# Why does the last call to inherited object appear to pass 100 instead of 50?

Tags: java, inheritance

I do not understand where I have gone wrong. It looks to be working okay until I get to the last call where the area of triangle is returned as 100 instead of 50. I thought that this works correctly because the variable hold which is of the class Field is assigned to b which is the object triangle. Please could you help me with my terminology and understanding of where this code has gone wrong.

```
public class Figure {
    double dim1;
    double dim2;

  Figure(double a, double b){
        dim1 = a;
        dim2 = b;
    }

 double area(){
     System.out.println("Area of shape is " + dim1*dim2);
    return  dim1*dim2; 
    }
}

public class Triangle extends Figure{
    double dim1;
    double dim2;

    Triangle(double a,double b){
       super(a,b);
        dim1 = a;
        dim2=b;
    }

    @Override

   double area(){
     System.out.println("Area of triangle is " + dim1*dim2/2);
    return  dim1*dim2; 
    }

}
public class RunFigure {
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
      Figure a = new Figure(10,10);
      a.area();

      Triangle b = new Triangle(10,10);
      b.area();

      Figure holder;

      holder = a;
      System.out.println("a area " + holder.area());

      holder = b;
      System.out.println("b area "  + holder.area());
    }
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have separate `dim1` and `dim2` elements in the derived class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Triangle, you overrode the area function like this:

```
   @Override
   double area(){
       System.out.println("Area of triangle is " + dim1*dim2/2); // should print 50
       return  dim1*dim2; // will return 100
    }
```

And System.out.println("b area "  + holder.area()); will print you one time
"Area of triangle is 50" and then it will take the return value and print "b area 100".

You need to change the calculation of the return value also.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would it print the return value of 50 only once and then print the value of 100 ? If b is assigned to triangle, would it not use the triangle method for area ?

Comment: oh wait, now I see. Gah.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Then please accept an answer. If not, please post your further questions

Answer (score 0):

You return a wrong value from `Triangle.area()`: you forgot to divide the result by 2.

Also, you don't need to define attributes `dim1` or `dim2`in `Triangle`: it just add confusion.